# Permit and transferFrom function called on an ERC20 which drained a specific token in my wallet

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan, security, transferfrom

I recently found out I've been drained of around 1600 $ALT tokens in two separate transactions a few days ago. It sucks to lose money, but it sucks even more if you never know how it happened and what you can do to prevent it in the future. So I'm trying to understand what I did that made it possible for the attacker to drain this token from my wallet.

This has been a Permit call on the token contract specifying my address as the owner and some other address as the spender:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x62dfb567541f1c9ac588ddd70051a1a7b173eba6d1b0e763530470886e3e7303

Do I understand it correctly that this transaction wasn't even signed by my wallet? For context this is my wallet address where the tokens where drained from: **0x69bEc9C8Fb9617F9325BFa7b464EA09C41d244B7**

Consequently, the following two transactions drained the token using the transferFrom function:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe7531b8dcdd421695fba0f7cc3c7a757dd71b4e4c7e640a5f4d26875eb0d1560
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5930b9cd062fbff2ff24162e53d8d41462c57021976e3d80cfdb64e4ac4bbc11

For what it's worth, I am usually very careful with clicking on links, connecting wallets etc. and I'm sure (almost) that I have not signed any transaction approving the spending of a token as wasn't active on ETH mainnet at the time. Furthermore I use a Ledger hardware wallet.

I would be very very thankful for anyone that could help understand the situation. I know the tokens are gone but I want to learn from this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you signed the permit authorization information on the phishing website. This operation does not require you to pay gas fees to call the contract. The authorized person can use your signature information to authorize the authorized person for you.

Comment: After digging into it, this seems to be the case unfortunately. Silly me.
I even had the discussion with a friend a few weeks ago telling him that signing a message can in no way cause you to lose your funds as it just proves ownership of your wallet and doesn't do any transactions.
I feel so dumb, but atleast I've learnt something now.